# No default icon in GNOME dash

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock, gnome-dash

When I open a `.desktop` file with missing icon its window appears as a completely transparent icon in my GNOME dash.

I think there used to be some default icon (purple gears) for this situation. The problem stays if I change the icon theme.

Any ideas on how I could get the gear icon (or something similar) back?

Using Ubuntu 18.10 with GNOME 3.30.2.

#### Picture:

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the missing icon]

Comment: can you attach a pic?

Comment: Is this a fresh install?

Comment: @RolandiXor no, not at all

Comment: I have a hunch. It could be related to MIME types. What is the output of `~/.local/share/applications/mime.cache`?